# Collaborative Multi Agent Path planning on directional and non-planar graph

Tags: constraint-satisfaction, routing, path

I am trying to implement a multi-agent path planning algorithm that works on non-planar graphs and large agents (that is, collisions may at the intersection of two edges and at points where the edges run beside each other, if the euclidean distance is small enough).

For context, one can imagine the given graph as representing tracks: the tracks have a given path in euclidean space which cannot be deviated from. Thus, intersections (points at which agents may change/choose their path) do not occur at every vertex but rather at very few nodes that connect tracks.
The tracks can intersect, making the graph non-planar. The distances between the intersections also vary. Circles in paths are possible and I would expect them to occur in this setting.

Every agent knows of the paths of the other agents.

I did find some literature on the general topic but it seems to focus on planar and mostly grid-like graphs. One can of course model a grid in the euclidean space with the positions but since the paths do not follow a grid pattern, this seems like an unfeasible approach.

I also found some previous work on non-planar path planning with large agents which simplified the problem to non-simultaneous movement which is not possible for my application.

Is there perhaps a simple approach I am missing to solving this problem? I would be delighted to learn about pointers in this problem space. Thank you!